# Make Sphinx singlehtml printer friendly

Tags: html, css, printing, python-sphinx

I have some documentation that has a requirement that is must be printable. We've been using the sphinx latexpdf targets to do this, but we find ourselves spending a lot of time messing around with latex parameters and trying to get formatting right, especially with table objects. It's much easier to maintain the necessary styles in CSS, and the HTML looks great out of the box. So, I'm trying to find a way to get the singlehtml file to print nicely.

I know that there are ways to make an HTML file printer friendly, but I can't seem to get it to work with Sphinx. For example, I tried to add a page break before each 1st level title. I added the CSS for h1, but it isn't printing with the page break.

I also need to get headers and footers on each page to display certain security markings. I know there are several methods for doing this in HTML, between CSS and table objects, I can make it work in a raw HTML file. I'm just trying to get sphinx to generate the right html objects. Can I put all sphinx content into a "body" table cell? (referencing the "Ultimate" method here: https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a)

Has anyone been able to modify the way that the sphinx documentation prints? Are there any examples of how to do the operations mentioned above in Sphinx?

Thank you.

Comment: What you get in terms of CSS/HTML depends in large part on the [Sphinx theme](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html) you use. Some parts are mostly fixed by Sphinx (like the generation of some target names) but most are theme dependent. My advice for you problem would be using the simplest possible theme with minimal options, possibly also turning [off most of the HTML options](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output).

Comment: By generating a second documentation with the above options, you could link to it using a 1:1 correspondence with each of your `.rst` pages. Afterwards applying a 3rd party software to the 2nd version of your documentation should give something very close to a printer friendly version which should leave you with the minimum amount of changes to tweak if necessary.